# Inheritance: Extending Model Classes in a sub-file

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do inheritance for a django model the following way:

```
from apps.main.models import Catalog

class ExtendedModel(Catalog):
    class Meta:
       abstract = True

    def print_hello(self):
        print 'hello!!'
```

However, when I try and use that method, it says it is not found:

```
>>> from apps.main.models_master_extension import ExtendedModel
>>> obj=ExtendedModel.objects.all()[0]
>>> obj
<Catalog: 81758604>
>>> obj.print_hello()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Catalog' object has no attribute 'print_hello'
```

What would be the correct way of extending the `Catalog` class in another file? The reason I need to do this is that the methods involved in the `Catalog` class extend 1000's of lines, and I want to separate some of them by function.

Comment: How did you create `c`?  You named your class `Catalog`, but its base class is also named `Catalog`, so it's not clear which one you used to instantiate `c`.

Comment: @BrenBarn please see the updated question. I think that should clarify it. I changed the class name.

Comment: You didn't change the class name, you just created an "alias" by importing it under a different name.  Your new class `Catalog` does not change what the old class `Catalog` does; you just created a new subclass with the same name as its superclass.  I don't know enough about Django to know where that class is being instantiated, but I bet you'll have an easier time debugging it if you change your `Catalog` class name to something else.  I suspect you will then see that `obj` is an instance of the "original" Catalog class and not your subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on additional methods to a model class, you need to set `proxy=True`:

```
from apps.main.models import Catalog

 class CatalogMasterTitleCreation(Catalog):
     class Meta:
        proxy = True
    def print_hello(self):
        print 'hello!!'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Comment: till this point I was thinking about some kind of reverse logic with abstract=True to Catalog xD